# unable to import dependency hadoop-core to build.sbt in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

```
my build.sbt looks like this


name := "Kafak"


version := "1.0"


scalaVersion := "2.12.2"


libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.8.1"


libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % 
"0.10.2.1"


libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.6.1"


// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-
 client
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % 
"3.0.0-alpha3"


// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-


core
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % 
   "2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.9.0"
```

i am getting the following error while importing it

Comment: the error i am receiving is because of the hadoop-core dependency

Comment: which error is that? please post details

Comment: **following error** where?

Comment: Try adding resolvers += "cloudera" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/"